# AWS ProfileCredentialsProvider not able to get credentials

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a file to S3. The code to do so is below:

```
AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new ProfileCredentialsProvider());
String key = String.format(Constants.KEY_NAME + "/%s/%s", activity_id, aFile.getName());
s3Client.putObject(Constants.BUCKET_NAME, key, aFile.getInputStream(), new ObjectMetadata());
```

The problem I am having is that my ProfileCredentialsProvider cannot access my AWS keys. I have set my environment variables:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY=keys go here
AWS_SECRET_KEY=keys go here
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=keys go here
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=keys go here
```

And as per [Amazon's Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html#config-settings-and-precedence) the set environment variables have precedence over any configuration files. This leads me to ask, why are my keys not being grabbed from my environment variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out.

If you specify a `ProfileCredentialsProvider()` the AWS SDK will look for a configuration file, regardless of precedence. Simply creating a S3 Client like this:

```
AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client();
```

Will check the various locations specified for credentials.